# Zend Framework Login Password Validation

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Havin a form that send's email and password to .php file to check if user exists in database.

login_form.php as following

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$email_login = $password_login = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email_login = test_input($_POST["email_login"]);
    $password_login = test_input($_POST["password_login"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}
```

And within class following lines of code to check

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();   
    $projectTable = new TableGateway('users', $this->adapter);      

    $rowset = $projectTable->select(array(
                                    //'email' => $this->email_login,
                                    'password' => $this->password_login,    
                                    ));
    $curRowSet = $rowset->current();
    foreach($curRowSet as $echoRow)
    {
        echo $curRowSet->id." ".$curRowSet->email." ".$curRowSet->username." ".$curRowSet->password."<br>";
    }
```

Where

1. $this->adapter make a Zend Db Adapter connection with database
2. table's name is users and has 4 rows

   ```
    id
    username
    email
    password
   ```

echoing all found values is done to test if there was found any match and

```
$this->password_login = hash('whirlpool', $this->password_login);
```

Was to done because from MySql Db password are also hashed like this. But following error appears>

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootSite\check\login_form.php on line 83

when i change

```
//'email' => $this->email_login,
'password' => $this->password_login,
```

to

```
  'email' => $this->email_login,
//'password' => $this->password_login,
```

There are 4 echoes of the same values. Also e-mail is unique.

My question here arrise: how can i compare 2 hashed passwords, one from $_POST variable another from MySql Db Table?

Comment: It seems your TableGateway returns incorrect result (looks like array of nulls). Check it.

Comment: when i check for email, there are no null values.

Comment: Did you checked manually `$this->password_login` with what you have in DB? Echo this value and make manual search in DB. Maybe it's not this same Hash?

Comment: I made some changed like trim(), stripslashes() before comparing them, this is the cause.